# C# run program from server

Tags: c#

Hi
Can i run  a  c# winform program from my internet server?For example i install the program my server.after that i want to run this program other computer unless install framework to client

Comment: Could you edit your question to be more clear? As written, it seems you are confused about what a server is; so I assume you mean something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) deployment.  (I'm guessing you mean that you want to host the winforms application)

Comment: I think he want to be able to run program from client **after** installing it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need one application running on your server that uses Windows Socket communication or similar which you can then use to trigger starting the other application since you generally can't remotely start applications remotely without remote desktop or similar. You can use FTP protocol with extensions to do this too I think but either way you'd most likely need one application running to trigger the other or use remote desktop.

Comment: My answer is for running the application on the server. To isntall and run remotely, the Click Once deployment mentioned by Nathan is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run it using Remote Desktop. You will not need .NET Framework on your client machine but the program will run on the server. So it will have access only to the server resources.